# Mantener Check Activado cuando se regresa de un pagina posterior

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Hola estoy implementando un check en mi html y cuando se da click y paso a la siguiente pagina y regreso el check ya no esta seleccionado y quisiera saber como mantener el check activado o como implementar el ng-checked

```
 oncheckvalidarTel(param:string){
      if(param=="Y"){
        this.isDisableTel?this.isDisableTel=false:this.isDisableTel=true;      
        this.clienteBean.clienteResponse.detalle.Cliente.numeroTelfMovil="";
        this.clienteBean.clienteResponse.detalle.Cliente.codTelfPais="";
      }
    }
```

en mi html quiero colocar el ng-checked pero no se que tipo de valor pasarle
si alguien me pudiera ayudar. gracias.

```
   <mat-checkbox  (click)="oncheckvalidarTel('Y')">
      No tiene
   </mat-checkbox>
```

Answer (score 1):

trata de usar el atributo [checked] para igualar a una variable iniciada, seria algo así:

```
<mat-checkbox [checked]="estado" (click)="oncheckvalidarTel()">
  No tiene
```

Y en el component.ts inicias la variable con el estado:

```
estado: boolean = true;
oncheckvalidarTel(){
  estado = !estado
  if(estado){
    this.isDisableTel?this.isDisableTel=false:this.isDisableTel=true;      
    this.clienteBean.clienteResponse.detalle.Cliente.numeroTelfMovil="";
    this.clienteBean.clienteResponse.detalle.Cliente.codTelfPais="";
  }
}
```